# C# with Mono or C++? (running Ubuntu)

Tags: c#, c++, linux, ubuntu

I need to write a program which connects to some databases and handles data within them. I must run Ubuntu. I have more experience with C#, but on windows..

Should I write the program using C# and Mono, or - would it make me many troubles and I should just go with C++? Thanks a lot!

Comment: Transitioning from C# to C++ would be much harder than transitioning from .Net to Mono, in my opinion.

Comment: It sounds like you should the language you know the best.  At this point of course, this topic is likely to be closed, since there isn't actually on topic question.

Comment: Actually, I think there is a topic - would using C# with Mono (on Linux) is very bad? What it can cause?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use Java or Python. I'm not a big fan of the concept of running .NET code on Linux and serialization in c++ is just a complete pain in the ass. If those are really your only two options I would probably do C# but I would recommend doing something entirely different. If you've written C# and c++ learning enough Java or Python to get this done won't be a whole lot of trouble.

Comment: Python seems very different for me (I'm writing mostly in C# and PHP). Java seems to be fine, but this program needs to be written very soon & I don't have much time to learn a whole new language. Would using C# in Linux is bad? I mean, what can it cause? All I need is to create some classes, run many IF statements and connect to MongoDB.

Comment: @EiTkoCaT There's nothing inherently wrong with it. I'm just skeptical of third party implementations of the CLR. Plus anyone who wants to execute your program has to have mono. If you have complete control over the environment it shouldn't be a serious problem although you may lose a lot of time dealing with configuration issues.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I should start try it myself - if I won't like using mono - I trust you and I'll go with Java! you better choose right. lol i'm just kidding, thanks again for your help!